# How can I return every index value up until given index in Fibonacci

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to print all Fibonacci values up until my given index.So for example if my index is 5, it should print 0,1,1,2,3,5. I tried the following:

```
public class FibPrac5202016
{
   static ArrayList <Long> list = new ArrayList<Long>();
public static void main(String [] args)  {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter index number: ");
    int integer = input.nextInt();
  FibPrac5202016 object = new FibPrac5202016();

System.out.println(object.operation(integer));
System.out.println(list.toString());
}

public static long operation(long n) {

     long number =0;
 if(n==0)
     number= 0;
 if(n==1)
     number = 1;
 try {
     if( n < 0)
     throw new Exception("Positive Number Required");

 }
 catch(Exception exc)
 {
     System.out.println("Error: " + exc.getMessage());
   System.exit(0);
 }
   if(n >1) {
  number = operation((n-1))+ operation((n-2));
   list.add(number);
}
   return number;
}

}
```

However, as you know it's recursion,it's printing all recursive calls.How can I reduce it a certain way so that I can only printout all index values up until the given index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with recursive Fibonacci is that the complexity is exponential. You have to make it iterative, it will be easier to print the terms.

```
// Compute the terms of fibonacci up to n
public static void operation(long n) {
    long a = 0;
    long b = 1;
    while (a <= n) {
        System.out.println(a);
        b = a+b;
        a = b-a;
    }
}
```

Comment: The explanation about the complexity is the best.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

//this program prints up to i-th Fibonacci number; 
//done by Nadim Baraky

public class Fibonacci {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     //declare and initialize three int variables 
     int a = 0, b = 0, c = 1;

     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 

     System.out.print("Enter index number: ");
     int i = sc.nextInt(); 

     sc.close(); //close the scanner object

     System.out.print(a + ",");

     //this loop does the flipping and addition 
     for(int n=1;n<=i-1;n++) {
        a = b; //set the variable a to have the value of b
        b = c; //set the variable b to have the value of c
        c = a + b; //set c to have the sum of a and b;
        System.out.print(b + ","); //prints up to the index entered;
     }

      System.out.print(c + "."); //prints the number at index i;

  }

}
```

Comment: I'm giving you upvote because it works but you did not explain why I can't use Fibonacci and why using iteration is better here.So I'm accepting the previous answer which has more explanation and very simple in nature. Have a great day!

Comment: thank you for your upvote and kind wishes; have a nice day; I can explain all what I've done if you still wish to know!